# dimension of page will require least amount of paper.

Tags: calculus

A page of book must have $\bf{18cm.}$ sq. of printed matter and must have $\bf{2 cm.}$ margins at top and

bottom and $\bf{1 cm.}$ margin on each side . What dimension of page will require least amount of paper.

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $\bf{x\; cm.}$ be the Length of paper and $\bf{y\;cm.}$ be the breadth of paper.

for least amount of paper means area of paper is minimum. So here we have to minimize area of paper.

Let $\bf{A}$ be the area of paper , Then $\bf{A = x\cdot y}$  and Given $\bf{(x-2)\cdot (y-4)=18}$

So $\bf{xy-4x-2y+8=18\Rightarrow xy-4x-2y=10}$ Now I did not understand how can we solve it.

Help Required

Thanks

Comment: You could try implicit differentiation and then set the derivative equal to $0$ to find a value for one of the dimensions that minimizes the area. And the just solve for the other dimension.

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to minimize (or maximize) a function, you generally rewrite the function in terms of one variable and use a derivative. So here, instead of completely expanding your second equation, solve it for $y$. So we get $y = \dfrac{18}{x-2}+4$. Substitute this into the equation for $A$ and get $A=x\left(\dfrac{18}{x-2}+4\right) = \dfrac{18x}{x-2}+4x$. Now take a derivative with respect to $x$, set equal to $0$ and solve. Check if resulting answer(s) correspond to a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

We make a comment about choice of variables. Suppose that we make the **printed** part $s\times t$ with $s$ the height and $t$ the width. Then $st=18$ and the total area is $(s+4)(t+2)$. This is $st+2s+4t+8$, which is $2s+4t+26$.

So we want to minimize $2s+4t$ subject to the condition $st=18$. If we want to use one variable calculus methods, we minimize $s+2t$, which is $s+\frac{36}{s}$. Now the "algebra" is quite simple.